# Adding text to the contents of the column?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I want to add `mark_` to the beginning of the data contained in the column `SYSLOCE2`.

How do I get this done automatically with query?

```
|---------------------|------------------|    |---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |      SYSLOCE2    |    |          ID         |      SYSLOCE2    |
|---------------------|------------------|    |---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       sample     |    |          1          |       mark_sample|
|---------------------|------------------|    |---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |       people     |    |          2          |       mark_people|
|---------------------|------------------| => |---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |       hello      |    |          3          |       mark_hello |
|---------------------|------------------|    |---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |       world      |    |          4          |       mark_world |
|---------------------|------------------|    |---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: If its only for selection then you can use `select concat('mark_', sysloce2) as sysloce2 from table `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to concatenate strings.

```
UPDATE elbat
       SET sysloce2 = concat('mark_', sysloce2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `update`:

```
update t
    set sysloce2 = concat('mark_', sysloce2);
```

In the more recent versions of MySQL, you could use a computed column instead.